# How to have a common input for different nb file

Tags: output-formatting, compile, input, input-forms

I have a set of five files. Each file takes a common input. But I need to change the input and run the files. The output of some file are used in other files. So how to do this. And also is there any ways to run all the files in some sequence. i.e just run one after the other in some sequence, and the final output will have the expected result.

Comment: The solution requiring the least work would be to leave everything as-is, create a "meta file" where you set the paramaters and run the notebooks using [`NotebookEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html) (see also [Workflow: Run a Notebook Programmatically](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/RunANotebookProgrammatically.html)).
Depending on what you want to do with this in the future, you might also consider writing a Package and creating a more robust framework.

Comment: How to create meta file?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing terminology, I meant creating a new notebook which calls your other notebooks.

Comment: Could you please direct me to the working example so that I can follow the instruction, and get the things working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is using `NotebookEvaluate`.

I will provide a minimal example, assuming all files are saved in the same directory.

I have a file `notebook1.nb` which depends on the value of some variable `a`, e.g.

```
(* notebook1.nb *)
Export["output.dat", a^2];
```

The notebook `notebook0.nb` can set the variable `a` and evaluate `notebook1.nb`

```
(* notebook0.nb *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
a = 2;
NotebookEvaluate[
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "notebook1.nb"}]
  ];
```

Note that `SetDirectory` is not strictly necessary, but ensures that `output.dat` is written to the same directory.

One can check that `output.dat` really gives the desired output

```bash
# output.dat
4
```

Comment: I will try to implement thanks, If I came across any problem I will tell you.